# How can I allow rotation of a USB-C port if I only have a single USB 3.1 lane connected to it?

Tags: usb, connector, usb-device, usb-c, usb-host

As a follow-up question to my [previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/650992/converting-two-usb-3-2-gen1-typea-connectors-to-one-usb-c-connector/650993?noredirect=1#comment1741263_650993) about connecting two 3.2 Gen1 Links to Type-C Connector, I learned that I can connect CC1 signal to 56K PU to VBUS and this pin-out supports one USB3.1 port, based on [USB-Type-C Cable and Connector Specification](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/USB%20Type-C%20Spec%20R2.0%20-%20August%202019.pdf):

[image]
According to this wiring table, I made the following design to support 1 link:
[image]

Now, let's say I want to connect another port in order to support USB-Type-C plug rotation (I can flip the cable and still have USB that works). that way, I can use the unconnected left pins (RX2+- and TX2+-) following the same concept I used before, and add another USB3.1 link (I just need to add 56K resistor to CC2). Thus, only the SBU signals will be left unconnected, and USB2.0 signals (D+, D-) will come from two different links, just like the USB3.1 signals.

Will that still work? I didn't see any  referral to this case in [USB-Type-C Cable and Connector Specification](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/USB%20Type-C%20Spec%20R2.0%20-%20August%202019.pdf).

Note: This is the work around I made for the fact the VL805-Q6 doesn't support USB Type-C Cable Rotation, and doesn't have integrated CC logic (like [ASM1543](https://www.asmedia.com.tw/product/85ayqa4SX4XSewIf/230yQc0rgeGp9TJ4) for example).

Note: my first priority is not to change VL805-Q6, but maybe add to it another simple chip where together, it's possible to achieve the wanted operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The USB reference you show is for a **cable** which allows you to connect a Type A host (e.g. a PC) to Type C device (e.g. a phone).

Your device has a **receptacle**.

It is the role of the device to understand which way the plug is inserted into socket and use a multiplexing circuitry to swap the pins to match the plug. Chips exists to manage this for you.

It is depicted in section 4.5.1.1 in the document you linked.

Comment: To address the OP's edit, the setup will look like this in the end: One VL805 port -> USB-C multiplexer -> USB-C port. The multiplexer will handle the CC logic and route the single lane from the VL805 onto one of the USB-C port's lanes, depending on the orientation of the plug.